# use stack native navigation and drawwer navigation in the same react native project

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

i used the native stack navigation to navigate bettween the screens (auth screens) ,but now i'm trying to create a humberger menu , when i click at the icon in the header , the menu open but i get an error "The action 'TOGGLE_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator.

Is your screen inside a Drawer navigator?

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production."                                             here is my in the differents screens

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,Dimensions,Image} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {TousCommandes} from '../screens/Restau/TousCommandes';
import {Livreurs} from '../screens/Restau/Livreurs';
import {Profile} from '../screens/Restau/Profile';
import {TousPlats} from '../screens/Restau/TousPlats';
import { HeaderPages } from '../components/HeaderPages';
import {HomeRestau} from '../screens/Restau/HomeRestau';




const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function AppDrawer(){

    return(
        
        <Drawer.Navigator >
            <Drawer.Screen
            name="TousCommandes"
            component={TousCommandes}/>

        <Drawer.Screen name="HeaderPages" component={HeaderPages} />

            <Drawer.Screen
            name="HomeRestau"
            component={HomeRestau}/>

        <Drawer.Screen
            name="Livreurs"
            component={Livreurs}/>

        <Drawer.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={Profile}/>

        <Drawer.Screen
            name="TousPlats"
            component={TousPlats}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>

    )

}
```

```
const Auth = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AuthNavigation(){
    return(

        <Auth.Navigator>


            <Auth.Screen
            name="Indexx"
            component={Indexx}
            options={{
               headerShown:false
              //...TransitionPresets.RevealFromBottomAndroid,
              //...TransitionSpecs.RevealFromBottomAndroid
              
            }}
            />
           
            <Auth.Screen
            name="Livreurs"
            component={Livreurs}
            options={{
               headerShown:false
              //...TransitionPresets.RevealFromBottomAndroid,
              //...TransitionSpecs.RevealFromBottomAndroid
              
            }}
            />
       // and other sreens
```

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
//import {  TransitionPresets   } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthNavigation from './AuthNavigation';
import AppDrawer  from './AppDrawer';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

export default function RootNavigator(){
    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
                
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AuthNavigation"
        component={AuthNavigation}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AppDrawer"
        component={AppDrawer}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>

        
        </NavigationContainer>
    )


}
```

```
export function HeaderPages({HeaderDrawer,navigation}){
    const igon=require("../../assets/arrow-back_2.png");
    const image = require("../../assets/hmbrgerMenu.png");
    return(
        <View style={styles.Header}>
      
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft:20}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>

                <Image source={igon}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{width: 30,height: 30,top: 10}} />
                
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.logoContainer} onPress={HeaderDrawer}>
                <Image style={styles.logo} source={image} resizeMode="contain" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            

       </View>
    )
}
```

```
export function TousPlats({navigation}){
    return(
       <View>
      
        <HeaderPages navigation={navigation} HeaderDrawer={()=>{navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}}/>
        

         <View><Text>Menu</Text></View>

         <View>
            <Text>Categorie</Text>
            <FlatList/>
         </View>
        </View>
        
    )

}
```

in app.js i just call the rootnavigator                                                                              i tried many method but nothing changes